# How to make a background image scrollable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, scroll, background-image, scrollable

I'm doing like a treasure map on my app. I had success to make the points(boards) on the map scrollable, but not the background. Because I'm also creating the art for the map itself, so before that I have to make everything works. In short I will demonstrate(I also marked a reference to help you). I got this [print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAeuh.jpg) and when I scroll up I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L3O9.jpg). See? The background image didn't follow the boards, didn't move. I already tried to put this background image with SingleChildScrollView but got worse, even the boards didn't move properly, the last one just cropped. I tried to put the image with a single child scroll view at the begin of the stack but didn't work too. Here is my code(I think you don't have to focus on these containers(they just show the boards and their positions), I'm almost sure that the problem is at the very start of the body):

```
body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Container(
          width: constraints.maxWidth,
          height: constraints.maxHeight,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage('https://i.imgur.com/z1GHi45.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth)),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Stack(children: [
              Wrap(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 20),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 115, top: 220),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 55),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60, vertical: 120),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 140, top: 120),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 100),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 300),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 150, top: 200),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, no one helped me so I solved this problem by myself. I found the solution multiplying the height of the background and adding the container above the Wrap widget. So, here is the code that worked for me:

```
body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Stack(children: [
              Container(
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * 2.4,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/z1GHi45.png'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover))),
              Wrap(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 20),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 115, top: 220),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 55),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60, vertical: 120),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 140, top: 120),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 100),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 300),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 150, top: 200),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => TelaConhecMangue_(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/f8lp7Fg.png')),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        );
      }),
```